# I`m not able to ubdate objects in parse

Tags: android, parsing, background, save

I am new using parse services, and I am learning how to use it. Actually I want to update an object which is in the parse`s database. It works perfectly, but when I use the function "object.saveInBackground()" nothing happen. This is my code:

```
public class ParseApplication extends Application {

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Parse.initialize(this, MY_APPLICATION_ID, MY_CLIENT_KEY);

    ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
    ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();

    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);

    ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);

        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");


            query.getInBackground("OBJECT_ID", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
              public void done(final ParseObject gameScore, ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Boolean.toString( gameScore.getBoolean("cheatMode")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                    toast1.show();
                    gameScore.put("cheatMode", true);

                    Toast toast =Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Boolean.toString( gameScore.getBoolean("cheatMode")), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                toast.show(); 
                                gameScore.saveInBackground();

                            }                   
              }
            });     
}
```

}

How can I update objects in parse?

Comment: Try gameScore.save() and refreshing parse class table. Sometimes it takes a minute. And are you sure you added the network permission?

Comment: That doesn`t works either. I can add new objects, and get its values, in fact I can see that toast1 shows "false" and toast shows "true" but parse table doesn`t change.

Comment: Try removing the following line: ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();

Comment: I`ve removed it and nothing changed